# How to build a c++ dll imported in unity/c#

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, hololens

I wanna build a c++ dll ,but I find there may be something wrong with my dll. I just built a simple  function for ARM64 to deploy it into Hololens2.
The header .h file :

```
#include "pch.h"


#ifdef  MYRESEARCHMODE_EXPORTS
#define DllExport __declspec(dllexport) 
#else  
#define  DllExport _declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef _cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

class  DllExports
  {
  public:
      DllExport   static  int __stdcall DOUT();

  };  

#ifdef _cplusplus   
}
#endif

The .cpp file like this:
#define MYRESEARCHMODE_EXPORTS

#include "pch.h"
#include"myResearchMode.h"

  int __stdcall DllExports::DOUT()
{
  return 123;
}
```

And I used the Dumpbin to test whether it is built successfully.
Then I import it in Unity/Plugin

```
    [DllImport("myResearchMode.dll", EntryPoint = "?DOUT@DllExports@@SAHXZ  ", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int DOUT();
```

But i find the result failed to show. I guess my dll has something wrong, do I forget to set some settings fot it ? Or where the error is ?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

Comment: I'd recommend to first see whether you can run a windows\linux variant of your DLL locally. Then try official examples on your target device: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/NativeRenderingPlugin Once both works, you can investigate what the differences are as to what you might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the C++ DLL? Which project template are you selected as the scaffolding when getting started to create a C++ DLL in the Visual Studio? If you created your C++ DLL as a Win32 binary, it will throw exceptions when running on the HoloLens2 because Unity will not include standard Win32 binaries when it builds a WSA project. Therefore, Therefore, it’s recommended to recreate or port a native win32 DLL to the UWP DLL, see the guidance here: [To port a native DLL to the UWP without creating a new project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/how-to-use-existing-cpp-code-in-a-universal-windows-platform-app?view=msvc-160#to-port-a-native-dll-to-the-uwp-without-creating-a-new-project)